# Still getting issue with right permission can't create directory "generation"*

Tags: magento2, nginx

I have already tried several solutions to solve my problem but it still does not work.
The "var / generation" folder is already under "777". "chmod -R -v 777"
I am under centOS7 and I use nginx and php-fpm 5.6
Thank you in advance for those who will help me

```
2018/09/30 00:46:31 [error] 19396#0: *132 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Can't create directory /usr/share/nginx/html//var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/ResourceConnection/.' in /usr/share/nginx/html//vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator.php:115
```

Answer (score 0):

In think you're using magento 2.2 and the error is becuase you've not given generated folder.
In magento 2.1 generation folder is located inside var, but in 2.2 in magento's root. So, run following command, and it should fix the error.

```
chmod 777 -R var pub generated
```

Comment: It still not working, my magento version is "2.1.7"

Answer (score 0):

verify that under var generation folder present? I think you deleted it.
if not present create it manually else run the following command with root user:

```
rm -rf var/generation/*
chmod -R 777 var/generation/
```

Comment: Not working too :(